# Insert rows for UITableView with animation (and update all other cells)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my tableview I have cells that have their background color set dependent if it's odd or even.

I want to insert new cells with animation `.top` to have them animate down from the top of the tableview.

However when doing this their is a discrepancy with the background colors of the cell. I understand when using `tableView.insertRows` it only calls the `cellForRow` for the inserted rows. Leaving the already existing cells to have their background color wrong.

I tried calling: 
`tableView.beginUpdates()`
`tableView.insertRows()`
`tableView.endUpdates()`

Don't really know how fix this issue. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to reload your table like this `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @Rajat you don't understand my issue. I don't want to reload because I want animation.

Comment: try adding your custom animation in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: @ConstantinSaulenco hmm you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just check the state of the first cell before inserting and arrange the backgrounds according to that cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [reloadRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) on all of the visible index paths.  You can get the visible index paths by calling [indexPathsForVisibleRows](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows).  This will force animation.

```
func reloadVisibleCells() {
    tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, with: .automatic)
}
```